# Shifting between activities (Android)

Tags: java, android

Shifting between activities isn't working.

What the app does is it opens the android.xml file then after 5 secs open the main file
Here's the code:

android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.android.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
        android:name="com.example.android.android"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANDROID" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>


</application>
```

android.java file:

```
package com.example.android;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class android extends Activity{
MediaPlayer sound1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.android);
    sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(android.this , R.raw.android);
    sound1.start();
    Thread timer = new Thread()
    {public void run()
        {
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ac){
                ac.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                Intent openactivity = new Intent            ("android.intent.action.MAIN");
            startActivity(openactivity);
            }

    }

};
timer.start();

 }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    sound1.release();
    finish();
}
}
```

Mainactivity.java:

```
package com.example.android;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new               PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

    }
```

android.xml file:(the first file that launches up)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background = "@drawable/android"    
>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: main xml file:(the file that it shifts to after 5 seconds)
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.MainActivity"
 tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" android:orientation = "vertical">
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/tv1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text = "hello!!!"
android:textSize = "40dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: read about explicit intents @ http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
 Intent openactivity = new Intent(android.this,MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(openactivity);
```

And for more information go to [starting-new-activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: it's still not working, the app doesn't load unless I change the android:name of the activities changing the intent categories from default to launcher and launcher to default in the android manifest but then the second activity just opens up.

Answer (score 1):

First, always Capitalise 1st letter of class names (code convention),

and then write your intents like below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent );
```

You can check [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) in Android Developers website.

Comment: it's still not working, the app doesn't load unless I change the android:name of the activities changing the intent categories from default to launcher and launcher to default in the android manifest but then the second activity just opens up.